# Como apagar cookies de um site?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um site http://www.meusite.com que cria vários *cookies* com domínios diferentes como: http://tracker.meusite.com e http://w3.meusite.com.

Como eu posso fazer em JavaScript para apagar os *cookies* do domínio **meusite**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código força a expiração de todos os cookies cujo escopo é o site atual:

```
function apagaCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Fonte: [Post original no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript).

Comment: @JorgeB. Por restrições de segurança você só pode manipular cookies que pertençam ao site onde se encontra.

Comment: Ok, obrigado :)